# Apply multi-variable function to columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I've got a DataFrame `data` containing columns C0, S0 and M0, say,

| C0 | S0 | M0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 0.2 | 2 |

. Now I want to judge whether C0 is between M0-2*S0 and M0+2*S0 for each row in `data` and write the result in a new column `data['J0']`. So I define such a 3-variable function `J`:

```
def J(mean,std,x):
    try:
        lowb=mean-2*std
        highb=mean+2*std
        if lowb<=x and highb>=x:
            return '-'
        if x>highb:
            return '↑'
        if x<lowb:
            return '↓'
    except:
        return nan
```

I think it is proper to use `.apply` to do this operation on columns M0, S0, C0 and store the result J in J0. However, I have only done this with mono-variable lambda functions. How to write `.apply` code exactly with this 3-variable function(`C0->x,S0->std,M0->mean`)? Thank you in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that uses `J` but takes a whole row at as argument:

```py
def vJ(r):
    return J(*r)

data['J0'] = data[['M0', 'S0', 'C0']].apply(vJ, axis=1)
>>> data
   C0   S0  M0 J0
0   1  1.0   5  ↓
1   2  1.0   5  ↓
2   3  0.2   2  ↑
```

However, note that this may be slow for large DataFrames. A faster option is to implement the logic of `J` with vectorized operations:

```py
# faster (suitable for large df)
lob = data['M0'] - 2 * data['S0']
hib = data['M0'] + 2 * data['S0']

data['J0'] = '-'
data.loc[data['C0'] > hib, 'J0'] = '↑'
data.loc[data['C0'] < lob, 'J0'] = '↓'
```

Comment: Does ```*r``` mean unpackaging Series ```r```?

Comment: yes, and I just noticed that the order of the columns is different than `mean, std, x`. Updated answer fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `lamba` function to pass your n arguments using apply.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_sample =\
pd.DataFrame([[1,1,5],
              [2,1,5],
              [3,0.2,2]], columns=["C0","S0","M0"] )

def J(mean,std,x):
    try:
        lowb=mean-2*std
        highb=mean+2*std
        if lowb<=x and highb>=x:
            return '-'
        if x>highb:
            return '↑'
        if x<lowb:
            return '↓'
    except:
        return nan
    
df_sample['J0'] = df_sample.apply(lambda x: J(x['M0'], x['S0'], x['C0']), axis=1)

print(df_sample)
```

Comment: What does ```df_sample=\``` mean?

Comment: is the name that I used for the dataframe variable. Just noticed you called it ``data``. And the ``\`` symbol was just to write it on a new line